# Is the following function differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having trouble solving the following true/false statement (prove or disprove):

Let $f$ be the following function :

If $\exists n \in N$ s.t.  $x = \frac{1}{2^n}$:
$$
f(\frac1{2^n}) =\frac{1}{(2^2)^n}
$$ 
Else:
$$
f(x) = 0
$$

Then $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\begin{cases}\lim\limits_{x\to0,\,x\neq\frac1{2^n}}\cfrac{0-0}x=0\\{}\\
\lim\limits_{x=\frac1{2^n}, x\to0\iff n\to\infty}\cfrac{\frac1{2^{2n}}-0}{\frac1{2^n}}=\lim\limits_{x=\frac1{2^n}, x\to0\iff n\to\infty}\cfrac1{2^n}=0\end{cases}$$

thus the function'sdifferentiable at zero.

Comment: Thank you! I was definitely over thinking the "meaning" of $\frac1{2^n}$. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

It is true. You can calculate $f'(0)$ using the differential quotient.